# Kitchen outlet and Light

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I am roughing in my kitchen wiring currently and have separated the counter top outlets so that I have two per circuit.  I also have a separate general lighting circuit in the kitchen.

My question is, can I use a two receptacle gangbox for one of the counter top outlets and a light switch if they are on separate circuits?

I am in Ontario in case it matters.

Answer (score 2):

As Tester said - it's quite common.  However, local ordinances (and national) can vary, so your mileage may vary.

Also, on the subject of kitchen outlets - make sure each circuit has GFCI protection - one protected outlet being the first outlet in each circuit (do not put two GFCIs on the same circuit).

May I ask why only 2 outlets per circuit?  Seems a tad light...

Comment: The way I understand the counter top outlets is that they are considered "small appliance" outlets and the most you can have on a circuit is 2.  What do you mean by my mileage may vary?  Are you saying it may not be allowed here afterall?

Comment: Different regions have different rules is all I mean.

Comment: I think you read that wrong.  You have to have two circuits.  You can put as many outlets in the kitchen and attached dining areas as you would like.

Comment: I am fairly certain that in Ontario you can only have two "small appliance receptacles per circuit".  I am not aware of any limit on the number circuits and plan on having more than two.

I appreciate the help from everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no problem having two circuits in a single box.  In fact, it's fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem, but remember, if you have multiple circuits in there that you're likely to have 240v going on and the risk of working in there without turning everything off is increased.

Make sure you turn off ALL the appropriate breakers before you work in there.

Also, as I commented elsewhere, there is no limit for the number of receptacles you can have on your domestic 20amp small appliance circuits.  You just need to have 2 to the kitchen that aren't shared with the dishwasher or garbage disposal or any overhead lighting.

You REALLY want more than 4 duplex receptacles in your kitchen!  In fact since all your counterspace has to be no more than 2' from a receptacle for code, it's almost a requirement!